# Tridion OData/CDS Examples

Tags: tridion

Can someone point me to some sample code for working with Tridion's OData Content Delivery web service? I found a couple articles on sdltridionworld.com, but they were pretty basic.

Comment: Tridion's Content Delivery Web Service is a regular OData provider, so a lot depends on the technology that you are using to access it. The most likely candidates are ASP.NET and Java. Which one are you looking to use?

Comment: It also helps if you tell explicitly what you are trying to accomplish , what you've already done yourself and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://blog.building-blocks.com/using-the-sdl-tridion-2011-odata-content-delivery-service-to-display-dynamic-content

If that doesn't help, as others have suggested, please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please be more specific on your question? As "Puf" mentioned if you could provide some context and what you're looking to accomplish, you might get more precised answers.

Having said that, here is [link](http://blog.building-blocks.com/using-the-sdl-tridion-2011-odata-content-delivery-service-to-display-dynamic-content) with an example code (.net) you can look at.